# Ignite CorruptedTreeException leads to cluster failure

Tags: ignite

I have a cluster of Ignite pods running on Kubernetes (AWS i3 instances using NVMe drives). When streaming data from Spark, they are crashing more often that I would like them to with this error message:

```
[SEVERE][data-streamer-stripe-2-#15][GridDhtAtomicCache] <MyCache> Unexpected exception during cache update
org.h2.message.DbException: General error: "class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.CorruptedTreeException: Runtime failure on row: Row@75ab6623[ key: CacheKey [idHash=242632156, hash=-841684964, parentId=-8607237606486310912, hour=9, id=-8607237528489033728, date=2018-09-09 00:00:00.0], val: CacheValue [idHash=843227122, hash=-801894604, theta=[2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 26, -52, -109, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 63, -37, 46, -109, -44, -43, -122, 18, 0, 122, -52, 59, -110, 53, 32, -44, 6, -98, 53, 74, 8, 21, -22, -36, 34, 84, 91, -95, -30, -55, 14, 107, 51, -60, -21, -31, 123, 124, 77, -17, 57, 80, 47, -20, 115, 107, 53, -121, 64, -24, -50, -24, 95, -123, -76, 1, 80, 14, 43, -118, -64, 94, 43, 109, 84, -106, -114, -94, 15, 98, -118, -12, 89, -76, 68, 119, -20, 10, 112, 7, 120, -120, -102, 122, 56, 126, 63, 94, 120]], ver: GridCacheVersion [topVer=157608673, order=1546229366985, nodeOrder=4] ][ 2018-09-09 00:00:00, -8607237528489033728, 9, -8607237606486310912, 02030300001acc930b0000000000803fdb2e93d4d58612007acc3b923520d4069e354a0815eadc22545ba1e2c90e6b33c4ebe17b7c4def39502fec736b358740e8cee85f85b401500e2b8ac05e2b6d54968ea20f628af459b44477ec0a700778889a7a387e3f5e78 ]" [50000-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:307)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.database.H2TreeIndex.putx(H2TreeIndex.java:302)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table.addToIndex(GridH2Table.java:546)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table.update(GridH2Table.java:479)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.store(IgniteH2Indexing.java:768)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.store(GridQueryProcessor.java:1905)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.store(GridCacheQueryManager.java:404)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.finishUpdate(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:2633)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.invoke0(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:1646)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:1621)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheOffheapManager$GridCacheDataStore.invoke(GridCacheOffheapManager.java:1935)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:428)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerUpdate(GridCacheMapEntry.java:2295)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateSingle(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2494)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.update(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1951)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1780)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1668)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.sendSingleRequest(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:299)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.map(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:483)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.mapOnTopology(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:443)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.map(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:248)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.update0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1153)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.put0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:611)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.put(GridCacheAdapter.java:2449)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.put(GridCacheAdapter.java:2426)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.put(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1105)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.put(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:820)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerCacheUpdaters$Individual.receive(DataStreamerCacheUpdaters.java:121)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerUpdateJob.call(DataStreamerUpdateJob.java:140)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.localUpdate(DataStreamProcessor.java:400)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.processRequest(DataStreamProcessor.java:305)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.access$000(DataStreamProcessor.java:60)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor$1.onMessage(DataStreamProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1569)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1197)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1093)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.StripedExecutor$Stripe.body(StripedExecutor.java:505)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.CorruptedTreeException: Runtime failure on row: Row@75ab6623[ key: CacheKey [idHash=242632156, hash=-841684964, parentId=-8607237606486310912, hour=9, id=-8607237528489033728, date=2018-09-09 00:00:00.0], val: CacheValue [idHash=843227122, hash=-801894604, theta=[2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 26, -52, -109, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 63, -37, 46, -109, -44, -43, -122, 18, 0, 122, -52, 59, -110, 53, 32, -44, 6, -98, 53, 74, 8, 21, -22, -36, 34, 84, 91, -95, -30, -55, 14, 107, 51, -60, -21, -31, 123, 124, 77, -17, 57, 80, 47, -20, 115, 107, 53, -121, 64, -24, -50, -24, 95, -123, -76, 1, 80, 14, 43, -118, -64, 94, 43, 109, 84, -106, -114, -94, 15, 98, -118, -12, 89, -76, 68, 119, -20, 10, 112, 7, 120, -120, -102, 122, 56, 126, 63, 94, 120]], ver: GridCacheVersion [topVer=157608673, order=1546229366985, nodeOrder=4] ][ 2018-09-09 00:00:00, -8607237528489033728, 9, -8607237606486310912, 02030300001acc930b0000000000803fdb2e93d4d58612007acc3b923520d4069e354a0815eadc22545ba1e2c90e6b33c4ebe17b7c4def39502fec736b358740e8cee85f85b401500e2b8ac05e2b6d54968ea20f628af459b44477ec0a700778889a7a387e3f5e78 ]" [50000-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.CorruptedTreeException: Runtime failure on row: Row@75ab6623[ key: CacheKey [idHash=242632156, hash=-841684964, parentId=-8607237606486310912, hour=9, id=-8607237528489033728, date=2018-09-09 00:00:00.0], val: CacheValue [idHash=843227122, hash=-801894604, theta=[2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 26, -52, -109, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 63, -37, 46, -109, -44, -43, -122, 18, 0, 122, -52, 59, -110, 53, 32, -44, 6, -98, 53, 74, 8, 21, -22, -36, 34, 84, 91, -95, -30, -55, 14, 107, 51, -60, -21, -31, 123, 124, 77, -17, 57, 80, 47, -20, 115, 107, 53, -121, 64, -24, -50, -24, 95, -123, -76, 1, 80, 14, 43, -118, -64, 94, 43, 109, 84, -106, -114, -94, 15, 98, -118, -12, 89, -76, 68, 119, -20, 10, 112, 7, 120, -120, -102, 122, 56, 126, 63, 94, 120]], ver: GridCacheVersion [topVer=157608673, order=1546229366985, nodeOrder=4] ][ 2018-09-09 00:00:00, -8607237528489033728, 9, -8607237606486310912, 02030300001acc930b0000000000803fdb2e93d4d58612007acc3b923520d4069e354a0815eadc22545ba1e2c90e6b33c4ebe17b7c4def39502fec736b358740e8cee85f85b401500e2b8ac05e2b6d54968ea20f628af459b44477ec0a700778889a7a387e3f5e78 ]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.doPut(BPlusTree.java:2285)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.putx(BPlusTree.java:2232)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.database.H2TreeIndex.putx(H2TreeIndex.java:299)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get page IO instance (page content is corrupted)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.io.IOVersions.forVersion(IOVersions.java:85)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.io.IOVersions.forPage(IOVersions.java:97)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.CacheDataRowAdapter.initFromLink(CacheDataRowAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.CacheDataRowAdapter.initFromLink(CacheDataRowAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.database.H2RowFactory.getRow(H2RowFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.database.H2Tree.createRowFromLink(H2Tree.java:217)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.database.io.AbstractH2ExtrasInnerIO.getLookupRow(AbstractH2ExtrasInnerIO.java:141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.database.io.AbstractH2ExtrasInnerIO.getLookupRow(AbstractH2ExtrasInnerIO.java:36)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.database.H2Tree.getRow(H2Tree.java:248)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.database.H2Tree.getRow(H2Tree.java:55)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.getRow(BPlusTree.java:5118)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.database.H2Tree.compare(H2Tree.java:327)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.database.H2Tree.compare(H2Tree.java:55)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.compare(BPlusTree.java:5105)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.findInsertionPoint(BPlusTree.java:5025)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.access$1300(BPlusTree.java:90)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$Search.run0(BPlusTree.java:291)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$GetPageHandler.run(BPlusTree.java:5615)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$Search.run(BPlusTree.java:271)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$GetPageHandler.run(BPlusTree.java:5600)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.util.PageHandler.readPage(PageHandler.java:159)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.DataStructure.read(DataStructure.java:334)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.putDown(BPlusTree.java:2499)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.doPut(BPlusTree.java:2252)
    ... 40 more
```

When I restart the pods, my Ignite cluster fails to restart and I get the following error message:

```
[SEVERE][exchange-worker-#53][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Failed to reinitialize local partitions (rebalancing will be stopped): GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=1], discoEvt=DiscoveryCustomEvent [customMsg=ChangeGlobalStateMessage [id=39389cff761-e26a5564-3e0b-40db-8d23-9b55baed8cb4, reqId=f7368209-3e64-4889-8125-11533195d465, initiatingNodeId=b88e2e48-9691-4ed7-975d-b638832a73d8, activate=true, baselineTopology=BaselineTopology [id=0, branchingHash=-518711786, branchingType='New BaselineTopology', baselineNodes=[2f1bae9c-b5c7-4255-b8b4-aca5fb462543, 29408921-5163-47af-9e14-cd0c83858ca5, 32bd1ab0-8060-478b-a3b9-f1d1c93d6e54, 7b893817-fc74-451d-987e-74f9d65956f1]], forceChangeBaselineTopology=false, timestamp=1546184663789], affTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=5, minorTopVer=1], super=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=b88e2e48-9691-4ed7-975d-b638832a73d8, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 100.96.2.1, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 172.25.40.134], sockAddrs=[/172.25.40.134:47500, ip-172-17-0-1.ec2.internal/172.17.0.1:47500, /100.96.2.1:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=5, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1546184663653, loc=false, ver=2.7.0#20181130-sha1:256ae401, isClient=false], topVer=5, nodeId8=4fa842da, msg=null, type=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, tstamp=1546184663805]], nodeId=b88e2e48, evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Unknown page IO type: 0
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.io.PageIO.getBPlusIO(PageIO.java:699)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.io.PageIO.getPageIO(PageIO.java:575)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.io.PageIO.getPageIO(PageIO.java:535)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.util.PageHandler.writePage(PageHandler.java:277)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.DataStructure.write(DataStructure.java:296)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.freelist.AbstractFreeList.insertDataRow(AbstractFreeList.java:500)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.freelist.CacheFreeListImpl.insertDataRow(CacheFreeListImpl.java:59)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.freelist.CacheFreeListImpl.insertDataRow(CacheFreeListImpl.java:35)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.RowStore.addRow(RowStore.java:103)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.update(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:2508)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheOffheapManager$GridCacheDataStore.update(GridCacheOffheapManager.java:1759)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.update(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:443)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.applyUpdate(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:2653)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.applyLastUpdates(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:2339)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.restoreState(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:1628)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.beforeExchange(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:1302)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.distributedExchange(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1453)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:806)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2667)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2539)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have two questions:

1. What are my options for recovering from this error with minimal loss of data?
2. What steps can I take to prvent these CorruptedTreeExceptions from happening in the future.

EDIT:

Spark to Ignite:

```
df.select(
    df.col("eventDate"),
    df.col("eventHour"),
    df.col("parentS2CellId"),
    df.col("s2CellId"),
    df.col("theta")
).write.format(
    FORMAT_IGNITE
).mode(
    "Append"
).option(
    OPTION_STREAMER_ALLOW_OVERWRITE, true
).option(
    OPTION_CONFIG_FILE, config.configFilePath
).option(
    OPTION_TABLE, "MyCache"
).save
```

Client Config:

```
<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="failureHandler">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.failure.NoOpFailureHandler"/>
    </property>
    <property name="binaryConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BinaryConfiguration">
            <property name="compactFooter" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="900000"/>
    <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="900000"/>
    <property name="systemWorkerBlockedTimeout" value="900000"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
    <property name="communicationSpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
            <property name="localPort" value="${TCP_COMMUNICATION_SPI_PORT}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="localPort" value="${TCP_DISCOVERY_SPI_PORT}"/>
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                    <property name="namespace" value="${K8S_NAMESPACE}"/>
                    <property name="serviceName" value="${K8S_SERVICE_NAME}"/>
                    <property name="masterUrl" value="https://${K8S_MASTER_URL}:443"/>
                    <property name="accountToken" value="${K8S_ACCOUNT_TOKEN_PATH}"/>                        
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Server Config:

```
<import resource="k8s.xml"/>
<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="failureHandler">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.failure.NoOpFailureHandler"/>
    </property>
    <property name="binaryConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BinaryConfiguration">
            <property name="compactFooter" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="3600000"/>
    <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="3610000"/>
    <property name="systemWorkerBlockedTimeout" value="3600000"/>
    <property name="publicThreadPoolSize" value="12"/>
    <property name="systemThreadPoolSize" value="12"/>
    <property name="queryThreadPoolSize" value="12"/>
    <property name="serviceThreadPoolSize" value="12"/>
    <property name="dataStreamerThreadPoolSize" value="12"/>
    <property name="stripedPoolSize" value="12"/>
    <property name="executorConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ExecutorConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="eventThetaThreadPool"/>
                <property name="size" value="32"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="checkpointFrequency" value="300000"/>
            <property name="storagePath" value="/var/lib/ignite/data/db"/>
            <property name="walFlushFrequency" value="10000"/>
            <property name="walMode" value="LOG_ONLY"/>
            <property name="walPath" value="/var/lib/ignite/data/wal"/>
            <property name="walArchivePath" value="/var/lib/ignite/data/wal/archive"/>               
            <property name="walSegmentSize" value="2147483647"/>
            <property name="maxWalArchiveSize" value="4294967294"/>
            <property name="walCompactionEnabled" value="false"/>
            <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="False"/>
            <property name="pageSize" value="4096"/>                
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="5242880"/>
                    <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
                    <property name="maxSize" value="61203283968"/>
                    <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="5242880"/>
                        <property name="name" value="OnDiskRegion"/>
                        <property name="maxSize" value="#{10 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="clientConnectorConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ClientConnectorConfiguration">
            <property name="port" value="10800"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="communicationSpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
            <property name="localPort" value="47100"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="discoverySpi" ref="tcp-discovery.cfg"/>
    <property name="connectorConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ConnectorConfiguration">
            <property name="port" value="11211"/>
            <property name="jettyPath" value="config/jetty.xml"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheKeyConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheKeyConfiguration">
                <property name="typeName" value="co.mira.etl.load.ignite.models.MyCacheKey"/>
                <property name="affinityKeyFieldName" value="parentS2CellId"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheConfiguration"> 
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="MyCache"/>
                <property name="queryParallelism" value="4"/>
                <property name="affinity">
                    <bean class="co.mira.etl.load.ignite.affinity.S2AffinityFunction">
                        <constructor-arg value="10"/>
                        <property name="maxPartitions" value="64"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="dataRegionName" value="OnDiskRegion"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                <property name="backups" value="0"/>
                <property name="sqlSchema" value="PUBLIC"/>
                <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="queryEntities">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                            <property name="keyType" value="co.mira.etl.load.ignite.models.MyCacheKey"/>
                            <property name="valueType"
                                  value="co.mira.etl.load.ignite.models.MyCache"/>
                            <property name="fields">
                                <map>
                                    <entry key="eventDate" value="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
                                    <entry key="s2CellId" value="java.lang.Long"/>
                                    <entry key="eventHour" value="java.lang.Byte"/>
                                    <entry key="parentS2CellId" value="java.lang.Long"/>
                                    <entry key="theta" value="[B"/>
                                </map>
                            </property>
                            <property name="keyFields">
                                <set>
                                    <value>eventDate</value>
                                    <value>s2CellId</value>
                                    <value>eventHour</value>
                                    <value>parentS2CellId</value>
                                </set>
                            </property>
                            <property name="indexes">
                                <list>
                                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                                        <constructor-arg>
                                            <list>
                                                <value>eventDate</value>
                                                <value>s2CellId</value>
                                                <value>eventHour</value>
                                            </list>
                                        </constructor-arg>
                                        <constructor-arg value="SORTED"/>
                                    </bean>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>  
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Please let us know the following:
1) Ignite version
2) NVMe drive's type (model, vendor)
3) Is JDBC thin or thick driver used?
4) Does the issue happen for UPDATEs, INSERTs or Spark operations?

In the meantime, opened a discussion on Ignite dev list for this issue: http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/Ignite-index-corruption-issue-gt-unrecoverable-cluster-td39869.html

The easiest recover option is GridGain Snapshots, community might suggest an alternate approach: https://docs.gridgain.com/docs/overview-snapshots

Comment: Ignite Version 2.7. Not sure about the nvme specs, here's the doc on aws: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ssd-instance-store.html. It's the default JDBC driver, so thin, I guess. It's on INSERT.

Comment: Can you explain your use case in detail, what exactly you're doing? It's possible it's a bug that have led to a tree corruption. AFAICS the error is in the indexes - that's fortunate, you should be able to just delete them (delete index.bin files) and they will be recreated. But we need to find out what order of events leads to them being corrupted. This reproduces multiple times, right? On a clean cluster? Please tell what do you do with caches, when do you start/stop/restart nodes, etc.

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce it, but it happens occasionally when seeding data from Spark onto a new cluster (it doesn't seem to happen immediately, but after the job has been running for a bit). I can add the spark job and the config to the question